# Parsing a Complex string in C#.

Tags: c#, parsing, vb6

I am Currently maintaining an application written in C#.  There is a new feature I need to code and I have hit a wall.

I am pulling data from a database for a different application written in VB6.  There is a field that holds data for a tree list.  I need to recreate this tree in my application.  The data looks like this:

```
{
    {
        table1~col_b^table1~colc^= 
    }|
    {
        {
            table1~col_b^table2~col_b^=
        }|{
            table2~col_a^table3~cola^=
        }|AND
    }|OR
}
```

I don't even know where to start.  What I need to accomplish is this.  {} denote an expression, | separate expressions. basically this tree should look like this:

```
OR
-- table1~col_b^table1~colc^= 
-- AND
---- table1~col_b^table2~col_b^=
---- table2~col_a^table3~cola^=
```

Any help or direction in solving this problem would be great!

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: If you want a start point, check for REGEX

Comment: Start by defining the grammar in detail. Basing a parser on one, or several, sample strings tends to result in much unhappiness.

Answer (score 3):

When you would define a grammar I suggest you looking at [Irony.net](https://irony.codeplex.com/). It allows to write parsers very easily. [Sample](https://irony.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=expression%20grammar%20sample&referringTitle=Home).

And this is rough grammar for your code:

```
    [Language("ExpressionEvaluator", "1.0", "Multi-line expression evaluator")]
    public class ExpressionEvaluatorGrammar : Grammar
    {
        public ExpressionEvaluatorGrammar()
        {
            // 1. Terminals

            var identifier = new RegexBasedTerminal("identifier", "[a-z\\d_^~]+");


            // 2. Non-terminals
            var root = new NonTerminal("root");
            var block = new NonTerminal("block");
            var expression = new NonTerminal("expression");
            var expressions = new NonTerminal("expressions");

            var prop = new NonTerminal("prop");
            var op = new NonTerminal("op");

            // 3. BNF rules
            op.Rule = ToTerm("OR") | "AND";
            prop.Rule = identifier + "=" ;


            expression.Rule = "{" + (prop | block) + "}" + "|" ;
            expressions.Rule = MakeStarRule(expressions,  expression);
            block.Rule = expressions  + op;
            root.Rule = "{" + block +"}";

            Root = root;
            //automatically add NewLine before EOF so that our BNF rules work correctly when there's no final line break in source
            this.LanguageFlags =  LanguageFlags.NewLineBeforeEOF;
        }
    }
} //namespace
```

It parses ok, all you need to do is add AST tree and use it.

[image: GramarExplorer window]

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional libraries, it's not too hard to parse this into an expression tree in pure C# code:

```
class TreeNode
{
    private enum ParseState
    {
        Operator,
        Expression
    }
    public static TreeNode ParseTree(string treeData)
    {
        Stack<TreeNode> parsed = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        StringBuilder nodeData = new StringBuilder();
        ParseState state = ParseState.Operator;

        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < treeData.Length; charIndex++)
        {
            switch (treeData[charIndex])
            {
                case '{':
                    nodeData.Clear();
                    state = ParseState.Expression;
                    break;
                case '\t':
                case ' ':
                case '\r':
                case '\n':
                case '|':
                    // ignore whitespace and |
                    break;
                case '}':
                    {
                        if (state == ParseState.Expression)
                        {
                            state = ParseState.Operator;
                            parsed.Push(new TreeNodeData(nodeData.ToString()));
                        }
                        else // Operator
                        {
                            TreeNodeOperators op = (TreeNodeOperators)(Enum.Parse(typeof(TreeNodeOperators), nodeData.ToString()));
                            TreeNodeExpression exp = new TreeNodeExpression();
                            exp.Operator = op;
                            exp.Right = parsed.Pop();
                            exp.Left = parsed.Pop();
                            parsed.Push(exp);
                        }
                        nodeData.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    nodeData.Append(treeData[charIndex]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return parsed.Pop();
    }
}

enum TreeNodeOperators
{
    AND,
    OR
}

class TreeNodeExpression : TreeNode
{
    public TreeNodeOperators Operator {get; set;}
    public TreeNode Left { get; set; }
    public TreeNode Right { get; set; }
}

class TreeNodeData : TreeNode
{
    public string Data {get; set;}
    public TreeNodeData(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You assume AND/OR are binary operators which is most probably not the case.

Comment: Yes this code does make some assumptions based on the limited information available, but it would not be hard to adjust to accommodate cases that don't fit these assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp to tokenize and a stack to parse recursively like this

```
        internal class Node
        {
            public string Terminal { get; set; }
            public List<Node> Operands { get; set; }
        }

        internal static readonly Regex TokensPattern = new Regex(@"(?<ws>\s+)|{\s*(?<value>[^\s}]+)\s*}|(?<token>OR|AND|.)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        static Node parseData(string str)
        {
            // init stack
            var stack = new Stack<Node>();
            stack.Push(new Node() { Operands = new List<Node>() });
            // define parser
            var parser = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>();
            parser.Add("{", _ => stack.Push(new Node() { Operands = new List<Node>() }));
            parser.Add("}", _ => { var top = stack.Pop(); stack.Peek().Operands.Add(top); });
            parser.Add("|", _ => { });
            parser.Add("AND", _ => stack.Peek().Terminal = "AND");
            parser.Add("OR", _ => stack.Peek().Terminal = "OR");
            parser.Add("", value => stack.Peek().Operands.Add(new Node { Terminal = value }));
            // execute parser
            TokensPattern.Matches(str).Cast<Match>()
                .Where(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["ws"].Value))
                .Count(m => { parser[m.Groups["token"].Value](m.Groups["value"].Value); return false; });
            // return top of the tree
            return stack.Peek().Operands[0];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string str = @"{
    {
        table1~col_b^table1~colc^= 
    }|
    {
        {
            table1~col_b^table2~col_b^=
        }|{
            table2~col_a^table3~cola^=
        }|{cccc}|AND
    }|OR
}";            
            // print tree function
            Action<int, Node> dump = null;
            dump = new Action<int, Node>((level, node) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new string(' ', level * 2), node.Terminal);
                if (node.Operands != null)
                    node.Operands.ForEach(el => dump(level + 1, el));
            });
            dump(0, parseData(str));
        }
```